# Duration of running for weight loss, and diet control

Tags: running, diet, weight-loss

I am not very good at running, but I need to get some weight loss for my little fat belly. I would like to go running because I don't know swimming and I got a fear for deep water(2m or more), shame on me.

I want to know how many time do I need to run in a week and how long I need to run? I welcome an answer in terms of how much time or how far to run.

And, how should I control my diet? I don't know how much calory do my meals have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have any experience with running, are overweight and a poor fitness, I always recommend [the Couch to 5K (C25K) program.](http://www.c25k.com/) Which consist of 3 to 4 workouts per week that last anywhere between 20-30 minutes of moderate exercise.

The reasons for this are:

- it assumes you have no running experience, so it takes the time to built up strength in your legs, so you shouldn't get injured
- it alternates between walking and jogging, as opposed to other programs that alternate between jogging and running. The walking intervals means you get plenty of rest and don't strain yourself. This also helps prevent overuse injuries.
- it starts out with very short, low intensity workouts, which again means you won't get injured, you shouldn't have a lot of DOMS and you should be able to complete each workout. That last part is important, because when done correctly **anyone** should be able to to finish C25K, which goes a long way for motivating people!

An important factor is that you should **never** run too fast. With which I mean you should 
be able to hold up a conversation while jogging, else its too fast. Yes, this almost certainly means some abysmally slow pace, but given that you were completely sedentary before you started, its a huge progress! Basically, you're not working out to lose pounds right now, you're working out to get into great shape, so you can lose pounds **after** the program.

The most important thing to focus on right now, is no excuses and getting started, keep it up and when you're done with C25K, pick a new target. Whatever you do, don't stop working out!

As for your diet, I believe that should be a different question, though the easiest way to track your calories is keeping a diary and spent some time figuring out how much calories are in everything you eat. Assuming your overweight because you eat too much and haven't worked out, cut out any candy and alcohol from your diet right now. You don't need the stuff and they will only make you fat.

Comment: I got 62kg weight and 172cm height, it shouldn't be very fat, but the fat just concentrate in my belly because I sit most of the time.

Comment: In that case you are rather slim, but simply need to workout more to change the fat to muscles :-) Regardless, just because your not fat, doesn't mean you won't get injured!

Comment: I'll just quickly point out that the fat being concentrated in your belly has nothing to do with the fact that you sit a lot. The location of fat is much more likely to be genetics and simple biology (fat gathers there in men to protect organs, etc.). This is my own understanding at least. If someone else has other information, please share.

Comment: I would want it to concentrate in my hands or legs....why belly?

Comment: I don't understand your comment @gunbuster

Comment: Can you give me some solid proof on the point that fat don't aggregate in the belly because of sitting a lot?

Answer (score 0):

Fat can also store on the belly if you are under stress.  If you are prone to stress and anxiety the body can burn fat from the arms and legs leaving you with slim limbs but leaving a pot belly... so something to check.

Comment: Please provide some reference to your claims as you are obviously not speaking about personal experience.