# Should I run along?

Tags: running, knees

I was advice to start c25k workout schedule in this [post](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/duration-of-running-for-weight-loss-and-diet-control), but as I run, I am worry about my knees. Today is my 4th workout since the start of c25k.

My knees have been strange since some years ago, even I didn't commit to running several times a week like now. The problem is when I walk, my knees feel very strange. I am no expert to biology, I can only describe it like this: The part where the knees connect to my lower legs feel like empty or lacking something in between.

The syndrome will not appear if I stand still or sit. When I run or walk faster so that the pressure increase, the feeling appears.

Oh, should I see the doctor again? Should I stop running, or running will heal this problem?

By the way, I don't workout in my life till now. In my university life, I spent 60 minutes walking to and from my school, would it sounds like the connective tissue wear out?

Here is the position I mention:
[image]

Comment: I also am not a biology guy.  Considering your situation, it sounds like your legs are lacking some of the supporting muscle strength it needs.  You can only build that by working on them.  What's your work/rest cycle look like?  (I'm not posting it as an answer because I'm not confident in this answer yet).  NOTE: I've also experienced a weird buckling sensation with my knees, but since I've started consistently working my whole body that has gone away.

Comment: Do you think this could be related: http://www.runnersworld.com/article/0,7120,s6-241-285--7773-0,00.html  (see notes on running distance increases etc.)  It also has stretches to help.

Comment: "The part where the knees connect to my lower legs feel like empty or lacking something in between." Can you perhaps take a photo or put an arrow on somebody else's photo. Because your knee has at least 3 major groups of tendons (on the outside) that keep your 'knee' together. So your description needs some additional information :)

Comment: I will take a photo when I back to home after work, thanks.

Comment: Are we still getting that picture @gunbuster? ;)

Comment: Oh, I just forgot that. Would upload it later.

Comment: Is the pain on your shin bone or the tendon between that and your knee cap?

Comment: I don't know the structure about leg bones...can you help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doctors are always good options when necessary. BUT all doctors will tell you to take time off.  Often you will and then resume training only to find the issue is still there.  Ugh!

There are 4 reasons why knees hurt from running.  They are

1. Weak Hips
2. Weak Thighs (Quads)
3. Tight Hamstrings
4. Tight IT Band

By strengthening the hips and thighs and improving flexibility in the hamstrings and IT Band, the pain should lessen and/or go away entirely.

Based off those ideas, here is a good routine to [Reduce Knee Pain from Running](http://christopherickes.com/running-blog/why-do-my-knees-hurt-from-running/).

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to see anymore stupid doctor only to tell me get rest.

Comment: @gunbuster363. Ha ha. I know! Also if you accept this answer, please mark accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Its true - i had shin splints for ages, and always tried training my shins and calfs but the actual problem was my hips' strength

Comment: Can you give more picture about the exercise? English is not my native language. Thanks.