# What should I look for in knee friendly running shoes?

Tags: knees, running-shoes

Just as the title says.

I am wondering if the air cushion in some sport shoes can reduce the pressure to my knees when I run,

Now I wear running shoes which have almost nothing, I adjust the pressure by running really slow. What can I look for in a running shoe that will reduce pressure on the knees when running?

Comment: I don't think the air cushion in sport shoes will really help reduce the pressure on your knees. The impact forces during are several magnitudes higher than during walking, a small air bubble isn't going to make you float :-)

Answer (score 3):

Cushioning may help prevent additional stress to your knee but it wont make the pain go away.

Check this thread for help on removing your knee pain while running. [Should I run along?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/should-i-run-along)

Also I recommend going to a specialty running shoe store to ensure you have the right type of shoe for your feet. Good luck and good running.

Comment: It very much depends on your gait. That's why there's different types of running shoes. You should go to a running shop