# I want to run but have a bad knee. How should I deal with it?

Tags: running, injury, legs

After the previous [post](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/should-i-run-along), I ran for 2 more times and then I stopped running because I felt that I needed to let the knee rest.

And then there is the feeling of discomfort in my knees, especially the right one, with no sign of getting better.

Do I need to train my leg muscle in order to get well? As the previous post suggested, there are 4 kinds of muscle I need to work with. Do I really need to train all 4 kind of muscle? Or is there a type of muscle held more responsible to the pain?

Comment: You should probably go see a doctor.

Comment: i have the same problem with my right knee also i've gone to see doctor after doctor the hospital says it should heal and so did the physical trainer and my pediactrics the knee heals but i keep injuring it. So far i've had 4 or 5 injuries on my right knee and i believe 1 on my left. The left doesn't hurt at all but the right only hurts if i twist it the right way i honestly don't know what to do or who to see anymore

Comment: PLEASE don't keep running.  I beg you.  As a collegiate D1 athlete, I ran through my injury 8 months ago and I'm barely able to walk after 7 months of "recovery".  My orthopedic surgeon is saying it could be permanent (osteochondral fracture), but there is a slim chance of improvement if I eventually get surgery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read you previous post and wonder why you're not seeing a Dr. or a Sports Therapist to determine what the issue is with your knees.  I go by the old advice of 'if it hurts, don't do it'.  If you continue to run, you run the risk of doing more damage.  If you do need to build up the muscles, tendons, etc. around your knees, I would recommend VERY light squats - and also look into the type of sneaker you're using for running and the surface you're running on.

Comment: Am I serious enough to see a doctor? But a doctor without x-ray inspection won't solve anything, and x-ray inspection will cost extra money....

Comment: @gunbuster363 - the cost of a blown acl or serious knee injury is more than the cost of a Dr's visit with xray

Comment: @gunbuster363  You can see a sports physical therapist without a doctor’s referral in most states.  They will evaluate the structure of your knees, the muscles, and your functional alignments.  You may not need xrays.  You can [find a physical therapist](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Find-a-Physical-Therapist.html) or [ask a therapist](http://www.moveforwardpt.com/category/ask-a-pt/) a question.

Comment: I would go to one of the Chinese Medical Traumatology and Orthopaedics in my local area first, they are famous among my area, and people will wait some hours to see him.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your body isn't (currently) built for running. Give it up and shoot for some other form of exercise instead, at least for the time being.

I'd go with [Stronglifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/stronglifts-5x5-beginner-strength-training-program/). Squats do great things for legs and knees, assuming you use correct form and follow the program (i.e. start light and get proper restitution). Perhaps after a few months you'll be fit for running.

Comment: What if I don't want to go into gym room? I got a pair of dumbbell, can I do the squat with them?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my right knee. In my case the problem was that my knee cap does not slide up and down in the correct position. I saw a physiotherapist who told me to run with my right foot turned in slightly. It was harder on the muscles in my thigh at first but the knee stopped hurting. I'm not saying it's the same for you but it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to see one of the Chinese Medical Traumatology and Orthopaedics in my local area first, as recommended by my brother. He said the doctor is good. And you don't need the referral letter from a generic doctor.